# Игра "Марио": нужен алгоритм падения марио после прыжка

Tags: python, разработка-игр, время, pygame

Создаю игру "Марио".При нажатии пробела значение move_3 == True , и чуть ниже идёт проверка , если move_3 == True , мне нужно что бы марио на 70 координат прыгал , а потом падал(без разницы с какой скоростью падал, просто нужен алгоритм) . Только нужно что бы это всё происходило постепенно , не сразу. Код:

```
import sys,time,pygame,random
pygame.init()

playSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
pygame.display.set_caption("Марио")
fpsController = pygame.time.Clock()
white = pygame.Color(255,255,255)
x1 = 100
y1 = 300
mario = pygame.image.load("Mario.png")
mario = pygame.transform.scale(mario,(50,60))

move_2 = False
move_3 = False
move_4 = False
def music():
    pygame.mixer.init()
    pygame.mixer.music.load('music.mp3')
    pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=-1)
while True:
    playSurface.blit (mario, [x1, y1])
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit ()
            sys.exit ()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit ()
                sys.exit()
            if event.key == ord("m"):
                music()
            if event.key == ord ("n"):
                pygame.mixer.music.stop ()


            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                move_2 = True

            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                move_3 = True

            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                move_4 = True

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:


            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                   move_2 = False

            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                move_3 = False

            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                move_4 = False
                    # if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    # x, y = event.pos

    if x1 >= 500:
        y1 += 5

    if move_2 == True:
        x1 += 5
        if x1 >= 730:
            x1 = 750
    if move_3 == True:


    if move_4 == True:
        x1 -= 5
        if x1 < 15:
            x1 = 15
    pygame.display.flip()
    playSurface.fill(white)
    fpsController.tick(15)
```

Comment: Особенно порадовала часть `// Тут вам надо написать код`, за вас не кто нечего писать не будет, это вам на фриланс форумы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция в классе Player

class Player():
     def **init**(self):
          #остальное
          self.jumpforce=0
          self.gravityforce=0
          self.maxgravityforce=50

```
  def gravity(self):
      #Событие начала прыжка игрока
      self.jumpforce=10 
      self.gravityforce=0
  def update(self,...):
     if self.gravityforce>self.maxgravityforce:
         self.gravityforce=self.maxgravityforce
     if self.jumpforce>0:
          if self.gravityforce<self.maxgravityforce:
               self.gravityforce+=1
    self.y-=self.jumpforce
    self.y+=self.gravityforce
```

Это пример. Просто есть сила прыжка и гравитации, понемногому сила гравитации растет и "перекрывает" силу прыжка, что делает падения плавным.

Answer (score 0):

Принцип такой(допишите в него то что вам надо):

```
import sys
import time
import random
import datetime
import threading

import pygame


pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption("Марио")

SCOPE = {}
SCOPE['th'] = None
SCOPE['x1'] = 100
SCOPE['y1'] = 300

WHITE = pygame.Color(255,255,255)
FPS_CONTROLLER = pygame.time.Clock()
PLAY_WINDOW = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
MARIO = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("mario.png"), (50, 60))

move_2 = False
move_3 = False
move_4 = False


def move_mario(play_vindow, mario, scope):
    start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    while (datetime.datetime.now() - start_time) < datetime.timedelta(minutes=3):
        scope['y1'] += 5
        play_vindow.blit(mario, (scope['x1'], scope['y1']))
        time.sleep(5)
    time.sleep(60 * 3)
    scope['y1'] = 0
    play_vindow.blit(mario, (scope['x1'], scope['y1']))
    scope['th'] = None


def init_music():
    pygame.mixer.init()
    pygame.mixer.music.load('music.mp3')
    pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=-1)


while True:
    PLAY_WINDOW.blit (MARIO, [SCOPE['x1'], SCOPE['y1']])
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            elif event.key == ord("m"):
                init_music()
            elif event.key == ord("n"):
                pygame.mixer.music.stop()

            move_2 = (event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT)
            move_3 = (event.key == pygame.K_SPACE)
            move_4 = (event.key == pygame.K_LEFT)

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            move_2 = (event.key != pygame.K_RIGHT)
            move_3 = (event.key != pygame.K_UP)
            move_4 = (event.key != pygame.K_LEFT)

    if SCOPE['x1'] >= 500:
        SCOPE['y1'] += 5

    if move_2:
        SCOPE['x1'] += 5
        if SCOPE['x1'] >= 730:
            SCOPE['x1'] = 750
    elif move_3 and (SCOPE['th'] is None):
       SCOPE['th']= threading.Thread(target=move_mario, args=(PLAY_WINDOW, MARIO, SCOPE))
       SCOPE['th'].start()
    elif move_4:
        SCOPE['x1'] -= 5
        if SCOPE['x1'] < 15:
            SCOPE['x1'] = 15
    pygame.display.flip()
    PLAY_WINDOW.fill(WHITE)
    FPS_CONTROLLER.tick(15)
```

Comment: Когда запуска в игре этот код,у меня  становится 2 картинки марио , одна из которых сверху , а вторая внизу , и они повторяют движения одна за одной. И ещё одна картинка марио пытается показаться

Comment: Ещё и ошибка есть:start_new_thread(self._bootstrap, ())
RuntimeError: can't start new thread

Comment: полный traceback ошибки киньте

Comment: Может я изменю вопрос , что бы было легче , и мне , и вам? А вы удалите или измените этот ответ